# R: Adding a Vertical Dotted Line to a Time Series Plot

Tags: r, visualization

I made the following plot in R:

```
# Generate weekly sales time series from 2000-01-01 to 2020-01-01
set.seed(123)
sales <- ts(rnorm(1040, mean = 100, sd = 50), start = c(2000, 1), frequency = 52)

  # Plot the time series with a vertical line at January 1, 2010
    plot.ts(sales, main = "Weekly Sales", xlab = "Date", ylab = "Sales", col = "blue", ylim = c(0, max(sales)*1.1))
```

[image]

**My Question:** I am trying to add a red dotted vertical line at 2010-01-01 . I tried to do this with the following code:

```
abline(v = as.numeric(as.Date("2010-01-01")), lty = "dotted", lwd = 2, col = "red")
```

I can't see the line - I tried to change the thickness but I still can't see it.

Can someone please show me how to do this correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: What about `abline(v = 2010, lty = "dotted", lwd = 2, col = "red")`? If day and month are needed, use a fraction from 1, i.e. day of the year / 365.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the line does not appear on the plot is that `plot.ts()` uses whole years b.c. as the time unit, while the output of `as.numeric(as.Date())` is in [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (i.e. seconds since 00:00:00 UTC 1970-01-01):

```
> as.numeric(as.Date("2010-01-01"))
[1] 14610
```

The solution to your problem is to use the same time unit for both the initial plot and the `abline()`. That's what the other answer suggesting a solution in ggplot does. If you'd rather stick to base R, the comment by @tpetzoldt has a simple way of getting what you want:

```
abline(v = 2010, lty = "dotted", lwd = 2, col = "red")
```

works for 2010-01-01. If you need a finer temporal resolution, calculate the day of the year first, divide by 365 and use that as the decimal. `lubridate` makes that quite easy:

```
mydate <- as.Date('2010-06-06')
abline(v = lubridate::year(mydate) + lubridate::yday(mydate)/365,
       lty = "dotted", lwd = 2, col = "red")
```

Or even better: use `lubridate::decimal_date()`.

**Full Answer:**

```
# Generate weekly sales time series from 2000-01-01 to 2020-01-01
set.seed(123)
sales <- ts(rnorm(1040, mean = 100, sd = 50), start = c(2000, 1), frequency = 52)

mydate <- as.Date('2010-06-06')

# Plot the time series with a vertical line at January 1, 2010
    plot.ts(sales, main = "Weekly Sales", xlab = "Date", ylab = "Sales", col = "blue", ylim = c(0, max(sales)*1.1))

abline(v = lubridate::decimal_date(mydate),
       lty = "dotted", lwd = 2, col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Or use `v = lubridate::decimal_date(mydate)`

Comment: @harre oh, I wasn't aware that existed - much better solution, I've incorporated that into the answer. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I m not sure why it doesn't appear on the plot. Here is a method by converting your `ts` to a data frame and using `ggplot2` methods,

```
library(ggplot2)

start_year <- start(sales)[1]
start_period <- start(sales)[2]

dates <- seq(as.Date(paste(start_year, 1, 1, sep = "-")) + (start_period - 1) * 7, 
             by = "week", 
             length.out = length(sales))

sales_df <- data.frame(Date = dates, Sales = c(sales))

ggplot(sales_df, aes(x = Date, y = Sales)) +
     geom_line(color = "blue") +
     geom_vline(aes(xintercept = as.Date("2010-01-01")), linetype = "dotted", color = "red", linewidth = 2)
```

Which gives

[image]